# Bizarre bug when pasting to DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, user-controls, copy-paste

I have a `DataGridTemplateColumn` than contains a `UserControl`:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Projection"
                                SortMemberPath="SelectedItem"
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ProjectionMethod.Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:DataGridComboBoxCellControl DataContext="{Binding}"
                                                       SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectionMethod.Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                       ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectionMethodsTextWrapper, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                       ErrorMessage="{Binding ProjectionMethod.ErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay}">

                    </local:DataGridComboBoxCellControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The `UserControl` bindings are done with `DependencyProperties` I set up inside the `UserControl` definition.

For the most part, the control works fine. But when pasting, even though the contents visually appear to be pasted, the cell never commits the paste contents to `ProjectionMethod.Value` (even though it is set as the `ClipboardContentBinding`). Debugging reveals that the setter of `ProjectionMethod.Value` is never even called.

Even more strangely, the constructor of the `UserControl` *is* being called during paste.  I have no idea why this is occurring. I am pasting to existing cells, no new rows are being created. I was assuming the `ClipboardContentBinding` routes straight to the underlying property `ProjectionMethod.Value`. Why the paste command is even bothering with UI controls is a mystery to me.

It seems this problem might require someone with a fairly deep understanding of WPF.

(Here is the current xaml of the `UserControl`. Right now it's basically a `TextBlock` and a `ComboBox` with a few other controls for displaying errors. Any lines with `ElementName=parentControl` are bindings to dependency properties. Both the `TextBlock` and `ComboBox` bind to the same `SelectedItem` DP.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataGridComboBoxCellControl"
         x:Name="parentControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MyStringToThicknessConverter x:Key="PopToOne" PopString="1" EmptyString="0"/>
    <local:MyStringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="PopToVis" PopString="Visible" EmptyString="Collapsed"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=parentControl, Path=ErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay}"
      IsEnabled="{Binding IsProjectionEnabled}" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="{Binding ElementName=parentControl, Path=ErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PopToOne}}" 
            BorderBrush="Red"/>
    <Control Grid.Column="0"
             Margin="1,0"
             Template="{DynamicResource local:MyStyleRef, ResourceKey=errorGrid}"
             Visibility="{Binding ElementName=parentControl, Path=ErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PopToVis}}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=parentControl, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
            Style="{DynamicResource local:MyStyleRef, ResourceKey=noText_ComboBoxStyle}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=parentControl, Path=ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=parentControl, Path=SelectedItem}"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Update**
I have now tried getting rid of the `UserControl` altogether and dumping its xaml code directly into the `DataTemplate` of the `TemplateColumn` - the same issue more or less. Visually the paste appears to execute, but the setter of `ProjectionMethod.Value` is never called and the viewmodel is therefore never updated. I am using the `OnPastingCellClipboardContent` command to paste.

Comment: post the full code and XAML of the usercontrol. BTW, if your usercontrol is not reusable it does not seem like a good idea to even have a usercontrol to begin with. And `DataContext="{Binding}"` is redundant.

Comment: @HighCore xaml posted, sorry for the delay. Yes I was hoping to reuse this code in multiple windows, so I guessed that `UserControl` was the way to go. Kinda figured `DataContext="{Binding}"`  line was redundant too, but I was trying everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I set the update trigger for the clipboard paste to `PropertyChanged`:

```
ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ProjectionMethod.Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

And now the value is being committed immediately when pasting. I don't know what the default behavior is supposed to be, but before the paste values were never committed, even after row leave. And still not sure why the `UserControl`'s constructor was being called.